# Get iFrame Contents Locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

so I've been trying to figure out how to get the contents (source code) of an iFrame from a different URL. I know it is not possible from cross domain restrictions, however, what if the html page was running on the desktop? Like a native desktop application built with html, would it be possible then?

```
var theIframe = document.getElementById("frame");
var theContents = theIframe.contentDocument.body;
```

Comment: The "source code" would be `theIframe.contentDocument.body.outerHTML`, or `.innerHTML` which would exclude the `body` tag. The requested URL should be on the [same domain though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), i.e. it should be a local file too.

Comment: So if the iFrame loads an external URL, there's no way to access the code? Even if the html which loads the iFrame is run on a native desktop app (i.e. localhost)?

Comment: Yep, the same-origin policy can't be circumvented no matter where you're hosting your app. Actually I might have slightly misundertood your question at first, and @mbejda's (removed) answer would be totally valid for the cross-origin case.